# How does binding parameters work in SQLite3 (with minimal example)?

Tags: c++, sqlite

Somebody recommended to use parameter binding in SQLite in order to speedup recurring queries. However, it does not work if I have multiple parameters for binding. I don't see my error. All SQLite functions return with SQLITE_OK...

Below, I have written a minimal example. It creates a table, makes three entries and then queries two times, one time with one bind parameter and one time with two. The first time returns with one result, which is correct. The second one returns with zero results and sqlite3_step() returns with 101 (SQLITE_DONE). Why does it not return one result also?

```
#include <vector>
#include <sqlite3.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  sqlite3 * pDB;
  int iReturn = sqlite3_open("./Test.db", &pDB);
  if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
    return 1;
  }

  // create table
  {
    std::string str = "CREATE TABLE Names(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(30))";
    iReturn = sqlite3_exec(pDB, str.c_str(), NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      sqlite3_close(pDB);
      return 1;
    }
  }

  // insert data using binding
  {
    std::string str = "INSERT INTO Names(Name) VALUES(?)";
    sqlite3_stmt * pStmt = nullptr;

    iReturn = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDB, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1, &pStmt, nullptr);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      sqlite3_close(pDB);
      return 1;
    }

    printf("The statement %s has %d parameter(s).\n", str.c_str(), sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(pStmt));

    std::vector<std::string> vecNames;
    vecNames.push_back("Smith");
    vecNames.push_back("Morpheus");
    vecNames.push_back("Neo");

    for (unsigned int i = 0, iEnd = vecNames.size(); i != iEnd; ++i)
    {
      iReturn = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, vecNames[i].c_str(), vecNames[i].size() + 1, nullptr);
      if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
        return 1;
      }

      if (sqlite3_step(pStmt) != SQLITE_DONE) {
        sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);
        sqlite3_close(pDB);
        return 1;
      }

      sqlite3_reset(pStmt);
      sqlite3_clear_bindings(pStmt);
    }

  }

  // query using one bind parameter
  {
    sqlite3_stmt * pStmt = nullptr;
    string str = "SELECT ID FROM Names WHERE Name=?1";
    iReturn = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDB, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1, &pStmt, nullptr);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      return 1;
    }

    printf("The statement %s has %d parameters(s).\n", str.c_str(), sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(pStmt));

    // fourth parameter is length = position of \0
    iReturn = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, "Neo", 3, NULL);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      return 1;
    }

    vector<string> vecResults;
    char cBuffer[1024];
    string strBuffer;
    while (sqlite3_step(pStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
      sprintf(cBuffer, "%s", sqlite3_column_text(pStmt, 0));
      strBuffer = cBuffer;
      vecResults.push_back(strBuffer);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);

    printf("Found %d results.\n", vecResults.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0, iEnd = vecResults.size(); i != iEnd; ++i)
    {
      printf("%d: %s\n", i, vecResults[i].c_str());
    }
  }

  // query using two bind parameters
  {
    sqlite3_stmt * pStmt = nullptr;
    string str = "SELECT ID FROM Names WHERE Name=?1 AND ID=?2";
    iReturn = sqlite3_prepare_v2(pDB, str.c_str(), str.size() + 1, &pStmt, nullptr);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      return 1;
    }

    printf("The statement %s has %d parameters(s).\n", str.c_str(), sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(pStmt));

    // fourth parameter is length = position of \0
    iReturn = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 1, "Neo", 3, NULL);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      return 1;
    }


    iReturn = sqlite3_bind_text(pStmt, 2, "3", 2, NULL);
    if (iReturn != SQLITE_OK) {
      return 1;
    }


    vector<string> vecResults;
    char cBuffer[1024];
    string strBuffer;
    while (sqlite3_step(pStmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
      sprintf(cBuffer, "%s", sqlite3_column_text(pStmt, 0));
      strBuffer = cBuffer;
      vecResults.push_back(strBuffer);
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(pStmt);

    printf("Found %d results.\n", vecResults.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0, iEnd = vecResults.size(); i != iEnd; ++i)
    {
      printf("%d: %s\n", i, vecResults[i].c_str());
    }
  }

  sqlite3_close(pDB);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: NB. Somewhat inconsistent code. Bad as a sqlite-sample.
- NULL vs nullptr.
- api usage: sqlite3_bind_text() - with or without the terminator.
- no those boost::scope_exit guards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the row is not a string.

Change the binding of your second parameter to `sqlite3_bind_int(pStmt, 2, 3);` and it should work fine.

Also, why do you have your name row as VARCHAR(30) instead of TEXT?

Comment: In SQLite, `VARCHAR` and `TEXT` mean exactly the same thing: It gives the column text affinity.

Comment: Why does sqlite3_bind_text() return SQLITE_OK if it cannot bind my parameter (which is of type TEXT) to the column ID (which is of type INTEGER)? Isn't this bad design if it does not warn me at least? (See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/31809625/4675398)

Comment: It can bind it just fine, but it cannot execute it.

Comment: Well great ;-). But sqlite3_step() returns SQLITE_DONE instead of something like SQLITE_BAD_BINDING. How can I debug what goes wrong? Please see my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31809625/4675398

Comment: Haha! My problem was that I did not have SQLITE_TRANSIENT as last parameter in sqlite3_bind_text(). SQLITE_TRANSIENT makes a copy of what I bind, which is necessary because the thing I bind only exists locally.