# Is there a way to reset the cursor in python with sqlite3?

Tags: python, sqlite

The outer loop in the following code only executes once. I understand why. Apparently, the cursor can do only one thing at a time, and the line that I have commented out was interfering with my loop.

I suppose I could create a second connection, but I'd like to avoid that if possible. Is there a way to store the cursor position just before the offending line of code, and restore it immediately afterwards?

```
        cursor.execute('SELECT ...;')
        fetch=cursor.fetchone()
        while(fetch):
            ...
            while(endTime<=timeEnd):
                if(timeZero<=startTime):
#                   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO chronology ...")
                ...
            fetch=cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 3):

No. You cannot (well....depends on the library but usually no). This is the definition of a cursor. However, you can have multiple cursors to do that:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
write_cur = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT ...;')
fetch=cursor.fetchone()
while(fetch):
    ...
    write_cur.execute("INSERT ...")
    ...
    fetch = cursor.fetchone()
```

However, in cases like this, I usually use `fetchall()` instead of `fetchone()` and prepare all cases of INSERT needed for performance reason:

1. (weak) usually the library handles fetch by calling C libraries. So use `fetchall()` to avoid too many switching between C and python
2. (strong) doing INSERT many times inside a loop is known to be slow even the SQL engine already cached the parsing result of the SQL command. Usually there is a much faster `executemany()` to allow passing a `list` of binding parameters to INSERT in this case (see [How does binding parameters work in SQLite3 (with minimal example)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31806336/how-does-binding-parameters-work-in-sqlite3-with-minimal-example))

and if you do so, you don't need another cursor.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, [MySQL Python connector cursors](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor.html) also don't appear to support any kind of reset functionality, though some Python APIs, such as ArcGIS as mentioned [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63496/140020), apparently have resettable cursors.

The ability to reset a cursor would be handy in situations where you want to traverse a cursor once to validate or debug query results prior to handing off the cursor to an object factory (or other code) for processing. After you've traverse the cursor, you would then reset it before the subsequent processing.

Transact-SQL cursors are resettable, when [declared as scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17318016/138325).